# Usage of "Expression<Func<Object, bool>>"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

please take a look at the following snippet:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    return filter != null ? this.ObjectSet.Where(filter) : null;
}
```

As for example:

```
public IQueryable<Department> Query(Expression<Func<Department, bool>> filter)
{
    return _context.Departments.Where(filter);
}
```

(original source: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/06/21/revisiting-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework.aspx)

Can anyone provide some concrete examples of how to go about actually calling the second method with an actual query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say get all departments with Sales over $100

```
var deparments = deparmentsRepository.Query(d => d.TotalSales > 100.0m);
```

Func and Expression> can both be declared the same way using lambda syntax.

In fact there's an example in the article (in the last code snippet) you linked to already for this.

```
foreach(var department in uow.Departments.Query(d => d.Budget > 150000)) { ... }
```

Given that Query returns IQueryable there's no reason you can't build into more complex queries.

```
var deparments = deparmentsRepository.Query(d => d.TotalSales > 100.0m)
    .Select(d => new { ... });
```

Assuming Manager and Department have a foreign key you don't need that join.

```
var deparments = deparmentsRepository.Query(d => d.Manager.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```